# Error initializing ledger with assets using hyperledger fabric tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the tutorial. So far I am able to start the chaincode in mychannel using the command:

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
```

After setting up the PATHs, I run the following to initialize the ledger

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

Then I get the following error:
`Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode basic has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode basic not found"`

I'm just following this tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/test_network.html

Please advise.

Comment: I think it's unfair to thumbs down my question.  It is a valid question and I am not able to proceed following the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fabric 2.3 is superceded by fabric 2.4 and so if there are any problems with tutorials then they won't be addressed. I would recommend using fabric 2.4 and following the guide here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html
If you want to install go chaincode make sure you have go 1.18 (the currently required version of go for fabric 2.4) installed first.

The error you describe suggests that the go chaincode did not install and that could be down to the fact that you are trying to use fabric 2.3

If you are using docker, make sure that you bring the network down to ensure all volumes and networks are pruned and when you download the docker images for fabric 2.4 make sure they are tagged as latest (to be sure you could untag the latest tag of all the fabric docker images)

Comment: I used 2.3 because I want to learn about wallets later on.  But if I choose version 2.4 or latest, I cannot see any documentation on wallets.  Why is it so?

Comment: Wallets are part of the legacy client sdks, 2.4 introduced a new client SDK which doesn't have the concept of wallets and as such the current client sdks are to be deprecated in favour of these new SDKs. I would recommend that if you are learning fabric then you should focus on 2.4. If you still want to learn about the legacy client sdks then you can still use them against fabric 2.4 and refer to the specifics in older versions of the docs. Fabric-samples still contain samples that use the legacy client sdks